# Divisorial contractions and singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, singularity-theory, divisors

I have a smooth $6$-fold $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ and a divisor $D\subset X$ cut out by a quadratic polynomial. I know that $D$ in singular along a smooth $3$-fold $Y\subset X$, and that if $Z$ is the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$ then the strict transform $\widetilde{D}\subset Z$ of $D$ is smooth and there is a birational morphism $f:Z\rightarrow W$ contracting $\widetilde{D}$.

Is this information enough to determine the dimension of $f(\widetilde{D})$ and the type of the singularity of $W$ along $f(\widetilde{D})$ (terminal/canonical, multiplicity of the singularity)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: f only contacts the strict transform of D?

Comment: Exactly, $f$ only contracts the strict transform of $D$ and it is birational on its complement.